# Is there any relation between Windows-Generated volume number and the HDD's hardware serial number?

Tags: windows, licensing, hard-drive

I wonder if there is any relation between Windows-Generated volume number and the HDD's hardware serial number which is allocated by it's vendor?
The problem is that we have distributed a software in which the licensing method is based on the Windows volume number, but that tends to change every time Windows is reinstalled even on the same computer.
We're trying to figure out a way to validate volume numbers after windows re-installation in case of using the same system hardware every time.

Comment: The usual solution is to use the machine's ethernet address instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not associated with hard drive serial number. It's just an arbitrary number generated every format.

There is a less changing number residing in Master Boot Record called DiskID but that changes too in case of recreation of the MBR (such as antivirus repair or just some low level action). You could however read it using `diskpart` command in Windows with commands: `select disk 0`, `uniqueid disk`.

As a viable option you can send a [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) request using [`DeviceIoControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty` as the `STORAGE_PROPERTY` to the given device and retrieve a unique identifier.

Another option is to enumerate devices using [user PnP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use PnP identifier to uniquely identify disks.

There is also an option to query WMI for [`Win32_PhysicalMedia`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class but I'm not sure how reliable it is.

I believe all solutions would require administrative privileges.

Comment: Thanks, But the adversary here is, the software is widely distributed to many users. We have to find a solution to fix this, or some how relate these codes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_%28computing%29

Comment: Nope, it didn't. Also bear in mind that lone link is discouraged in SO.

Comment: How are you retrieving the volume numbers? There is a KB which shows, that DiskPart.exe displays different volume numbers, each time you start it.

Comment: The volume number is the same one retrieved by `dir` command.